# Is there any method to disable maven version autoincrement while jenkins job builds?

Tags: jenkins, version-control, maven-3, jenkins-plugins, maven-plugin

My maven version is increasing in each jenkins job build is there is any method to disable it,any scripts or any maven plugin change for it.

Thanks,
Jose

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins itself does not increment anything: the definition of your job does.

If you are using an old [M2+Release+Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin) or a more recent [Release+Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Release+Plugin), they would execute a `mvn release:prepare/perform`, which by default does increment the version (and also pushes to Nexus if you have configured one)

In your case, Jenkins does increment a [variable named `BUILD_NUMBER`](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables), that you may be using in your job, as in:

```
mvn clean install -Dbuild.number=${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

So in the end, it really depends on the exact nature of your Jenkins job.